# How to send dynamically filled HTML via email with php?

Tags: php, html, newsletter

I have such html which needs to be sent via email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style>
            #mainWrapper,body,html{height:100%;width:100%}body,html{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:15px}#mainWrapper{position:relative;background-color:#fff}#mainWrapper .logo{position:absolute;top:24px;left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto}#mainWrapper .checkMeOut{position:absolute;top:20px;left:49.5%;right:0;margin:0 auto}#formWrapper{position:absolute;top:99px;left:0;background-color:#f5f5f5;border-top:1px solid #dde0e6;width:100%}.tableWrapper{position:relative;max-width:804px;background-color:#fff;border-radius:5px;padding:20px 38px;margin:71px auto 20px;border-left:1px solid #cfcfcf;border-right:1px solid #cfcfcf}.tableWrapper:after{content:"";position:absolute;bottom:-8px;left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;width:880px;height:8px}#tableDecoration{display:block;margin:-112px auto 0}#dateField{color:#4b4b4b;font-size:15px;line-height:34px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid rgba(164,164,164,.53);border-radius:18px;padding:0 15px;position:absolute;top:41px;left:91px}.title{text-align:center;padding:31px 0 40px;font-size:21px;line-height:21px}table td,table th{border-bottom:1px solid #dde0e6;vertical-align:middle;padding:25px 35px 19px 34px}table{width:100%;border-top:1px dashed #dde0e6}table th{width:25%;text-align:right}table td{border-left:1px solid #dde0e6}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <div id="formWrapper">
                <div class="tableWrapper">
                    <div id="dateField">6/12/2015</div>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpading="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Campaign ID:</th>
                            <td><?php echo $campaignID ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Campaign Title:</th>
                            <td><?php echo $campaignName ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email:</th>
                            <td><?php $campaignName ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Start/ End:</th>
                            <td><?php echo $startDate . - . $endDate ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is just 1/3 of the whole content. Just did not want to paste everything in here. As you can see some parts are dynamically filled with php. My question is what is the best way to grab this and send as html.

I am using phpmailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Body= $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

One of the options might be to grab everything line by line and apply to one variable, but this looks to me not very convenient.

Another option might be to have a separate file:

```
$body = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/template/index.html');
```

But not sure how to handle those dynamically values when.

Maybe some kind of templating system can be used? But not sure how to handle this as well.

Comment: i think use file_get_contents(path_to_html_file) to read full compact content from your html file is best way .because it is easy and long content can be compact in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build templateing logic with dynamic values inside based on just php `str_replace()` function

**1)** create email templates with variables inside in this syntax `{variable_name}`

```
 ....
 <div> Hello {name} </div>
```

**2)** create `getEmailTemplate($tempalte, $variablesArr)` function where you will read your email $tempalte and process with `str_replace`

**3)** make loop in `getEmailTemplate` over `$variablesArr` and replace all variables with their values inside `templateHTML`

```
// Example for above html $variablesArr = array('name' => "Your user name")
foreach($variablesArr as $key => $value) {
   $templateHTML = str_replace("{".$key."}", $value, $templateHTML);
}
```

Comment: Will go this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example you could use it:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
// optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {
    echo "Message sent!";

}
```

Comment: Not sure what this does: eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body); And as far as I know eregi is deprecated.

Comment: it's deprecated, you could use quotemeta() [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quotemeta.php)